# 502 error when scraping LinkedIn using scrapy with splash

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I tried scraping the Linkedin company page for Netflix using Scrapy with Splash. It works perfectly fine when I use scrapy shell but gives 502 error when I run the script.

Error:

```
2017-01-06 16:06:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-01-06 16:06:45 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-01-06 16:06:52 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.linkedin.com/company/netflix via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 502 Bad Gateway
2017-01-06 16:06:55 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.linkedin.com/company/netflix via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 2 times): 502 Bad Gateway
2017-01-06 16:07:05 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET https://www.linkedin.com/company/netflix via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 3 times): 502 Bad Gateway
2017-01-06 16:07:05 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (502) <GET https://www.linkedin.com/company/netflix via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
2017-01-06 16:07:05 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <502 https://www.linkedin.com/company/netflix>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2017-01-06 16:07:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

In Splash Terminal:

```
2017-01-06 10:36:52.186410 [render] [139764812670456] loadFinished: RenderErrorInfo(type='HTTP', code=999, text='Request denied', url='https://www.linkedin.com/company/netflix')
2017-01-06 10:36:52.205523 [events] {"fds": 18, "qsize": 0, "args": {"url": "https://www.linkedin.com/company/netflix", "headers": {"User-Agent": "Scrapy/1.3.0 (+http://scrapy.org)", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Accept-Language": "en"}, "uid": 139764812670456, "wait": 0.5}, "rendertime": 6.674675464630127, "timestamp": 1483699012, "user-agent": "Scrapy/1.3.0 (+http://scrapy.org)", "maxrss": 87956, "error": {"info": {"url": "https://www.linkedin.com/company/netflix", "code": 999, "type": "HTTP", "text": "Request denied"}, "error": 502, "description": "Error rendering page", "type": "RenderError"}, "active": 0, "load": [0.51, 0.67, 0.8], "status_code": 502, "client_ip": "172.17.0.1", "method": "POST", "_id": 139764812670456, "path": "/render.html"}
2017-01-06 10:36:52.206259 [-] "172.17.0.1" - - [06/Jan/2017:10:36:51 +0000] "POST /render.html HTTP/1.1" 502 192 "-" "Scrapy/1.3.0 (+http://scrapy.org)"
```

Code for spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from linkedin.items import LinkedinItem


class LinkedinScrapy(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'linkedin_spider'  # spider name
    allowed_domains = ['linkedin.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.linkedin.com/company/netflix']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, 
                           endpoint='render.html', args={'wait': 0.5)

    def parse(self, response):
        item = LinkedinItem()
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="stream-promo-top-bar"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/h1/span/text()').extract_first()
        item['followers'] = response.xpath('//*[@id = "biz-follow-mod"]/div/div/div/p/text()').extract_first().split()[0]
        item['description'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="stream-about-section"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/p/text()').extract_first()
              yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because LinkedIn is denying access because of useragent string your request is using:

```
"User-Agent": "Scrapy/1.3.0 (+http://scrapy.org)"
```

You should change user-agent in your spider to something else, see [mozillas documentation for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent/Firefox)

Comment: Well if LinkedIn's T&C's says its allowed to scrape them... oh WAIT it doesn't. Plus, if they BLOCK him from scraping, you would think that they don't ALLOW it and someone actually took the time to BLOCK his scrape attempts.

Comment: @zerohero the data is public so terms and conditions are irellavent. Please educate yourself on the legality of web-scraping before leaving these comments.

Comment: I think you're the one that needs the education. The data may be public, but it's against their terms for you to use automatic scraping utilities as it causes unnecessary server resources to be used when they can't generate revenue from it whatsoever. I've been around the block with this AND the legalities surrounding it several times.

Comment: @zerohero Please read: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-legality-of-web-scraping. Even __if__ it was stealing, robbing, mugging or whatever you might call it - it's completely irrelevant when it comes to an education website that is stackexchange.